# CSS animation, just changes images with no animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change photos with a fade like animation but they just switch between themselves,

any idea how to fix it or what I am doing wrong? thank you in advance.

CSS:
.slider{

```
width: 300px;
height: 400px;
background: url("images/flip1.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 300px 300px;
animation: slide 20s ease-in-out;
```

}

@keyframes slide{
25%{

```
    background: url("images/flip2.png");
    background-size: 300px 300px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
50%{
    
    background: url("images/flip3.png");
    background-size: 300px 300px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
75%{
    background: url("images/flip4.png");
    background-size: 300px 300px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
100%{
    background: url("images/flip1.png");
    background-size: 300px 300px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

}

html:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it could help you.

```css
.slide-container {
    position: relative;
}

.slide1 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    background: red url("images/flip1.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 300px 300px;
    animation: slide1 20s ease-in-out;
    position: relative;
}

.slide2 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    background: blue url("images/flip2.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 300px 300px;
    animation: slide2 20s ease-in-out;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.slide3 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    background: green url("images/flip3.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 300px 300px;
    animation: slide3 20s ease-in-out;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.slide4 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    background: yellow url("images/flip4.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 300px 300px;
    animation: slide4 20s ease-in-out;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

@keyframes slide1 {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    20% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    95% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes slide2 {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    20% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    45% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes slide3 {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    45% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    70% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    75% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes slide4 {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    70% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    75% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    95% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide1"></div>
    <div class="slide2"></div>
    <div class="slide3"></div>
    <div class="slide4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can remove the background color of each slide.

Answer (score 0):

Use prefixes for other browsers

```
 -webkit-animation: 4s linear 0s infinite alternate move_eye;
     -moz-animation: 4s linear 0s infinite alternate move_eye;
       -o-animation: 4s linear 0s infinite alternate move_eye;
          animation: 4s linear 0s infinite alternate move_eye;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/animation

Comment: added it, still all the same :( i think its because my background is a url for an img

Comment: I have copied your code and run it on my laptop. It is working. I think, there is a cache @YohanLeykin

Comment: Try to reload page with Ctrl + F5

Comment: saved the file with the new line,reloaded the site, but the images are still changing with no effect.

Comment: @YohanLeykin use your code, it is small and cool. It is not working on firefox because of "-moz-" prefix.

Comment: The background image doesn't animate.